# Query all queues I am a member of

Tags: apex, soql, query

I would like to query **all hardcodequeue groups I am a member of**. So far it seems I can only query a queue if I hard-code it's name. There doesn't seem to be a way to query a queue and have it return if memberId=:someUserID

```
List<Id> qId = [select id from Group where type='Queue' AND Name='Test Queue']; //gives queue with the name test queue
List<Id>userID = [select UserOrGroupId from GroupMember where GroupId IN:qid]; //gives users in groups
```

Comment: Did my answer point you in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by querying from the `GroupMember` object and accessing Group fields with the `Group` relationship.

```
SELECT 
    Group.Name
FROM 
    GroupMember 
WHERE 
    UserOrGroupId = 'YOUR-USER-ID' 
    AND Group.Type = 'Queue'
```

If you want to check if a user is a member of a specific Queue then you can use the following query and if it returns `null` then they are not a member of that queue.

```
SELECT 
    Group.Name
FROM 
    GroupMember 
WHERE 
    UserOrGroupId = 'YOUR-USER-ID' 
    AND Group.Type = 'Queue'
    AND Group.Name = 'YOUR-QUEUE-NAME'
```

Comment: My understanding is that this will only work where a user is a "direct" member of the queue. Where the queue membership includes Roles, Roles and subordinates or other public groups, this approach will not work. I bring this up because I'm looking for a solution to this problem at the moment!

Comment: I agree with Bigears, I currently have a Queue that contains Roles and Subordinates, but  this was not working. I had to add each user to the queue individually.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? @JonDuelfer @ Bigears